# What should I do about this Xcode organizer error when trying to export a snapshot?

Tags: xcode4, snapshot, organizer

This is in Xcode 4.5 Organizer on the 'Projects' screen. I have lots of snapshots including many made after updating to Xcode 4.5. If I select one of them (it doesn't matter which one) then click "Export Snapshot" I get a dialog box with this message:

fatal: ambiguous argument 'ae30b7dea8b5..a934b593abf6': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions.

This makes all of my snapshots useless. Can anybody explain what's going on and how to get around it?

I don't actually need to recover a snapshot right now so if I could fix this error I could just trash all the old ones and make a new one.

Comment: Further: if I select "Restore Snapshot" from the Xcode File menu, all the same snapshots appear. If I choose one and click restore, I get the comment "File does not exist in restore location."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the cause but I fiddled around and found out how to fix it. In Xcode 4.5 click File => "Project Settings" then on the Snapshots tab select "Custom" for Snapshots location and enter a new location. I entered ~/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots but it probably doesn't matter what you enter. Then the "Create Snapshot" and "Restore Snapshot" items in the File menu work, referring to the new custom location.

Surprisingly, the Organizer "Export Snapshot" now works too! Weird!. It refers to the old location and all the old snapshots are still there and now they can be accessed and exported without the error message. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Like many problems in Xcode, i just did cmd + Q and restarted Xcode. And now it works as expected. So at the very least please try that!