# Restore Snapshot - File does not exist in restore location

Tags: xcode5, snapshot

Using xcode 5:  I can create a snapshot without an error.  But sometimes when I want to restore it (FILE->RESTORE SNAPSHOT) I run into this error.

I know there have been a few questions about this problem, e.g. [What should I do about this Xcode organizer error when trying to export a snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825674/what-should-i-do-about-this-xcode-organizer-error-when-trying-to-export-a-snapsh).

Creating a new snapshot directory solves the problem for the moment.  But after 1 or 2 days the same problem arises. So i keep renaming my snapshot directory and loose all old snapshots.

I also don't want to use the organizer and export snapshot function as mentioned for example here: [Manually recover files from Xcode snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311146/manually-recover-files-from-xcode-snapshot)

I would like to use the quick access FILE->CREATE / RESTORE SNAPSHOT

So it would be great if someone has an idea how to eliminate the root cause.

**EDIT:**

I know now what and how it happens.  Still don't know how to solve it properly.

The error message occurs on files which I have locally deleted or renamed.  I have done this within xcode and I have said "Move to Trash".  It seems like that git (and so the snapshot feature) is not informed about the deleted file.  So it complains that there are files that do not exist in restore location.  The restore itself works.

But and this is still my problem: a restore will recover all the old deleted files and I end up cleaning everything up again and again.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?  Thank you very much.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I ran into this tonight. Sometime after removing some files, an alert popped up in Xcode going on and on about all the GIT mistakes I was making. Since I dont do any raw git commands, I tried to press on. From that point on, the auto snapshot only lists the deleted files with the "file does not exist" text in the diff window. None of the touched files actually are listed. Manual snapshot still seems to work.

Comment: Sorry no real solution found. At least I know now I am not the only one. I was already wondering since there was no feedback at all here. Maybe one of the gurus will have a clue?